# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox'

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am trying to perform the same operation on multiple pictureboxes but the first line of the following code is generating this error:

```
Unable to cast object of type System.Windows.Forms.Button to type System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
```

So I was wondering if anyone could be of assistance. Thanks in advance.

```
For Each pb As PictureBox In Me.Controls
    Dim bp As New Bitmap(pb.Image)
    pb.Region = GetRegion(bp, Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 255))
    pb.Image = Nothing
    pb.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Yellow)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

The `For Each` is looping over all the controls in `Me.Controls`

You need to check for the `PictureBox` type before you start operating on the control

```
For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is PictureBox Then
        Dim bp As New Bitmap(ctrl.Image)
        ctrl.Region = GetRegion(bp, Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 255))
        ctrl.Image = Nothing
        ctrl.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Yellow)
    End If
Next
```